# Changing the value of JSON object's key, changes other values also

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, key-value

**Description**: Have defined a JSON Object, as a global variable.
`var JSON_OBJECT = [];`

```
[
{
    "user_id": "123",
    "AF": [
        {
            "formula_type": 0,
            "lag": 0
        }
    ],
    "Trend": [
        {
            "is_active": 0
        }
    ]
},
{
    "user_id": "859",
    "AF": [
        {
            "formula_type": 0,
            "lag": 0
        }
    ],
    "Trend": [
        {
            "is_active": 0
        }
    ]
}
]
```

JSON object `(JSON_OBJECT)` gets constructed by a function:`jsonCreator`

```
function jsonCreator() {

var af_Array = [];
var Trend_Array = [];
var selectedUsers = ['123','859','235']

for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    var af_keys = {}
    af_keys.formula_type = i;
    af_keys.lag = i;
    af_Array.push(af_keys);
}

for (var j = 0; j < 1; j++) {
    var trends_keys = {}
    trends_keys.is_active = j;
    Trend_Array.push(trends_keys);
}


for (var indexUsers = 0; indexUsers < selectedUsers.length; indexUsers++) {
    var jsonObj = {};
    jsonObj.user_id = selectedUsers[indexUsers]['rowId'];
    jsonObj.AF = af_Array;
    jsonObj.Trend = Trend_Array;
    JSON_OBJECT.push(jsonObj);
}
};
```

**Problem Statement**: Change the value of `formula_type` for `user_id:123`

**Tried Below Code**

```
var currentUserID = '123';
var formulaType = 'FORMULA-1'

Object.keys(JSON_OBJECT).forEach(function(k) {
if (currentUserID == JSON_OBJECT[k]['user_id']) {
    JSON_OBJECT[k]['AF'][0]['formula_type'] = formulaType;
}
});
```

**Issue Facing**:
Above code changes the value of `formula_type` for `user_id:123` and `user_id:859`

**Resulting JSON**:

```
[
{
    "user_id": "123",
    "AF": [
        {
            "formula_type": 'FORMULA-1',
            "lag": 0
        }
    ],
    "Trend": [
        {
            "is_active": 0
        }
    ]
},
{
    "user_id": "859",
    "AF": [
        {
            "formula_type": 'FORMULA-1',
            "lag": 0
        }
    ],
    "Trend": [
        {
            "is_active": 0
        }
    ]
}
]
```

Help would be appreciated.

```js
var JSON_OBJECT = [
{
    "user_id": "123",
    "AF": [
        {
            "formula_type": 0,
            "lag": 0
        }
    ],
    "Trend": [
        {
            "is_active": 0
        }
    ]
},
{
    "user_id": "859",
    "AF": [
        {
            "formula_type": 0,
            "lag": 0
        }
    ],
    "Trend": [
        {
            "is_active": 0
        }
    ]
}
];

var currentUserID = '123';
var formulaType = 'FORMULA-1'

Object.keys(JSON_OBJECT).forEach(function(k) {
  if (currentUserID == JSON_OBJECT[k]['user_id']) {
      JSON_OBJECT[k]['AF'][0]['formula_type'] = formulaType;
  }
});
console.log(JSON_OBJECT);
```

Comment: can you try data[0].AF[0].formula_type = "3";..where data will be JSON

Comment: Your code works see the snippet. What's the problem now?

Comment: This could be a problem with the way `JSON_OBJECT` is created. Those two `AF` values are likely referencing the same array, or the elements in the `AF` arrays are referencing the same object. That shouldn't happen with proper json objects of course but if you're creating those objects yourself then the bug might be there.

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal, Added more details to the question.

Comment: @ccarton, Yes i am creating JSON with a function. verified, have not seen any issue in creating it, added more information to the question.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is in the creation. This line: `jsonObj.AF = af_Array;` doesn't copy, it just assigns a reference. All of the `AF` fields are referencing the same `af_Array` object. You need to do a deep copy. Same for the `Trend_Array` assignment.

Comment: If you're not sure about how to do a deep copy, the easiest way is to convert to and from a json string. i.e when `af_Array` is created save it as a string `af_Array_str = JSON.stringify(af_Array)` and then when you create your objects use `jsonObj.AF = JSON.parse(af_Array_str)`

Comment: @ccarton
Kudos, working smoothly now, using your suggestion before  **forEach**
`var JSON_OBJECT1 = JSON.stringify(JSON_OBJECT); 
    JSON_OBJECT = JSON.parse(JSON_OBJECT1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The problem was with the creation of JSON, `jsonCreator()`. Line `jsonObj.AF = af_Array;` was not copying, it was just assigning a reference.

Solution found, with the suggestion of `@ccarton`, converted JSON_OBJECT to string and parse back.

```
var currentUserID = '123';
var formulaType = 'FORMULA-1'

var JSON_OBJECT1 = JSON.stringify(JSON_OBJECT); 
JSON_OBJECT = JSON.parse(JSON_OBJECT1)

Object.keys(JSON_OBJECT).forEach(function(k) {
if (currentUserID == JSON_OBJECT[k]['user_id']) {
    JSON_OBJECT[k]['AF'][0]['formula_type'] = formulaType;
}
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    
        var currentUserID = '123';
  var formulaType = 'FORMULA-1';
        
        var JSON_OBJECT = '[{    "user_id": "123",    "AF": [        {            "formula_type": 0,            "lag": 0        }    ],    "Trend": [        {            "is_active": 0        }    ]},{    "user_id": "859",    "AF": [        {            "formula_type": 0,            "lag": 0        }    ],    "Trend": [        {            "is_active": 0        }    ]}]';

        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(JSON_OBJECT);
       // var obj1 = jQuery.parseJSON(JSON_OBJECT);
$.each(obj, function(k,value) {
  if(value.user_id == currentUserID){
    JSON_OBJECT.AF = formulaType;
    obj[k]['AF'][0]['formula_type'] = formulaType;
  }
}) 
  var myJSON = JSON.stringify(obj); 
        console.log(myJSON)
  
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Using Array map() method :**

```js
var jsonObj = [
{
    "user_id": "123",
    "AF": [
        {
            "formula_type": 0,
            "lag": 0
        }
    ],
    "Trend": [
        {
            "is_active": 0
        }
    ]
},
{
    "user_id": "859",
    "AF": [
        {
            "formula_type": 0,
            "lag": 0
        }
    ],
    "Trend": [
        {
            "is_active": 0
        }
    ]
}
];

var currentUserID = '123';
var formulaType = 'FORMULA-1';

jsonObj.map(obj => {
  if (obj.user_id == currentUserID) {
    for (var i in obj["AF"]) {
      obj["AF"][i].formula_type = formulaType;
    }
  }
});

console.log(jsonObj);
```

**Using JavaScript for ... in loop :**

```js
var jsonObj = [
{
    "user_id": "123",
    "AF": [
        {
            "formula_type": 0,
            "lag": 0
        }
    ],
    "Trend": [
        {
            "is_active": 0
        }
    ]
},
{
    "user_id": "859",
    "AF": [
        {
            "formula_type": 0,
            "lag": 0
        }
    ],
    "Trend": [
        {
            "is_active": 0
        }
    ]
}
];

var currentUserID = '123';
var formulaType = 'FORMULA-1';

for (var i in jsonObj) {
  if (jsonObj[i]["user_id"] == currentUserID) {
    for (var j in jsonObj[i]["AF"]) {
      jsonObj[i]["AF"][j].formula_type = formulaType;
    }
  }
}

console.log(jsonObj);
```

Answer (score 1):

The code snippet below works:

```js
var JSON_OBJECT = [
{
    "user_id": "123",
    "AF": [
        {
            "formula_type": 0,
            "lag": 0
        }
    ],
    "Trend": [
        {
            "is_active": 0
        }
    ]
},
{
    "user_id": "859",
    "AF": [
        {
            "formula_type": 0,
            "lag": 0
        }
    ],
    "Trend": [
        {
            "is_active": 0
        }
    ]
}
];

var currentUserID = '123';
var formulaType = 'FORMULA-1'

Object.keys(JSON_OBJECT).forEach(function(k) {
  if (currentUserID == JSON_OBJECT[k]['user_id']) {
      JSON_OBJECT[k]['AF'][0]['formula_type'] = formulaType;
  }
});
console.log(JSON_OBJECT);
```

**Good luck !**

Answer (score 1):

Try following:

```
if (JSON_OBJECT.length > 0) {
    JSON_OBJECT.forEach(function(obj, index) {
    if (obj.user_id == 123) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty('AF')) {
        obj.AF.forEach(function(obj, index) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty('formula_type')) {
            obj.formula_type = 'FORMULA-1';
          }
        });
        }
    }

  });
}
```

Explanation: Here `JSON_OBJECT` is an array of objects. So we need to loop into the array first.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cfLmuo29/6/)