# Javascript: I am updating the value of an object key. BUT after the update another key pair also changes value

Tags: javascript, json, javascript-objects, updating

I 'm working on an API for an invoicing programm. My problem is that when I am trying to constuct a json and update some keys, a key, changes without me updating it.

Here is a MRE without all the api calls. I am just using prepared objects, for data.

```js
const business = {
   vatNumber: '050112718',
   country: 'GR',
   branch: 0
}

const customer = {
   vatNumber: '050112915',
   country: 'GR',
   branch: 0,
   postalCode: 28100,
   city: 'Argostoli'
}

const invoiceProperties = {
   series: 0,
   aa: 1,
   issueDate: '2021-12-15',
   type: '1_1',
   currency: 'EUR'
}

const payment = {
   type: 3
}

const product = {
   price: 10,  
   taxCode: 1,    
   classificationType: 'type a',
   classificationCategory: 'category 1',
}

const lines = [
   {
      lineNumber: 1,  
      netValue: 0.00,
      vatCategory: 0,
      vatAmount: 0,      
      incomeClassification: {
        'icls:classificationType': '',
        'icls:classificationCategory': '',
        'icls:amount': 0.00
      }

   },   
   {
      lineNumber: 2,  
      netValue: 0.00,
      vatCategory: 0,
      vatAmount: 0,      
      incomeClassification: {
        'icls:classificationType': '',
        'icls:classificationCategory': '',
        'icls:amount': 0.00
      }

   },   
   {
      lineNumber: 3,  
      netValue: 0.00,
      vatCategory: 0,
      vatAmount: 0,      
      incomeClassification: {
        'icls:classificationType': '',
        'icls:classificationCategory': '',
        'icls:amount': 0.00
      }

   }   
]

// json invoice creation
const invoiceObj = {
   
   invoice: {
      issuer: {
         vatNumber: business.vatNumber,
         country: business.country,
         branch: business.branch
      },
      
      counterpart: {
         vatNumber: customer.vatNumber,
         country: customer.country,
         branch: customer.branch,
         address: {
            postalCode: customer.postalCode,
            city: customer.city
         }
      },
      
      invoiceHeader: {
         series: invoiceProperties.series,
         aa: invoiceProperties.aa,
         issueDate: invoiceProperties.issueDate,
         invoiceType: invoiceProperties.type,
         currency: invoiceProperties.currency
      },
      
      paymentMethods: {
         paymentMethodDetails: {
            type: payment.type,
            amount: ""
         }
      },
      
      invoiceDetails: [],     
      
      invoiceSummary: {
         totalNetValue: 0,
         totalVatAmount: 0,
         totalWithheldAmount: '0.00',
         totalFeμesAmount: '0.00',
         totalStampDutyAmount: '0.00',
         totalOtherTaxesAmount: '0.00',
         totalDeductionsAmount: '0.00',
         totalGrossValue: 0,
         incomeClassification: []
      }
   }
}

//making paths into object more simle
const invoiceDetails = invoiceObj.invoice.invoiceDetails;
const summaryClassification = invoiceObj.invoice.invoiceSummary.incomeClassification;

const makeLines = ()=> {

   for (const line of lines) {
        
      line.netValue = product.price.toFixed(2);
      line.vatCategory = product.taxCode;
      line.incomeClassification["icls:classificationType"] = product.classificationType;
      line.incomeClassification["icls:classificationCategory"] = product.classificationCategory;
      line.incomeClassification["icls:amount"] = product.price.toFixed(2);
      
      switch (line.vatCategory) {
         case 1:
         line.vatAmount = (line.netValue * 0.24).toFixed(2);
         break;
         case 2:
         line.vatAmount = (line.netValue * 0.17).toFixed(2);
         break;
         case 3:
         line.vatAmount = (line.netValue * 0.13).toFixed(2);
         break;
         case 4:
         line.vatAmount = (line.netValue * 0.09).toFixed(2);
         break;
         case 5:
         line.vatAmount = (line.netValue * 0.06).toFixed(2);
         break;
         case 6:
         line.vatAmount = (line.netValue * 0.04).toFixed(2);
         break;
         case 7:
         line.vatAmount = '0.00';
         break;
         case 8:
         line.vatAmount = '0.00';
         break;
      };
      
      console.log(line); //just to see something in dev mode

      invoiceObj.invoice.invoiceSummary.totalNetValue = (invoiceObj.invoice.invoiceSummary.totalNetValue/1 + line.netValue/1).toFixed(2);
      invoiceObj.invoice.invoiceSummary.totalVatAmount = (invoiceObj.invoice.invoiceSummary.totalVatAmount/1 + line.vatAmount/1).toFixed(2);
      invoiceObj.invoice.invoiceSummary.totalGrossValue = (invoiceObj.invoice.invoiceSummary.totalGrossValue/1 + line.netValue/1 + line.vatAmount/1).toFixed(2);

      const lineClassification = line.incomeClassification;
      const lineType = lineClassification["icls:classificationType"];
      const lineCategory = lineClassification["icls:classificationCategory"];

      const classificationIndex = summaryClassification.findIndex(o => o["icls:classificationType"] === lineType && o["icls:classificationCategory"] === lineCategory);

         
      // if there isn't a array item with the same combination of categories, we add the classifications object
      if (classificationIndex < 0) { 
         summaryClassification.push(lineClassification);   
      } else {  // else if there is a an item in the array with the same categories, we add the amount of the item to the total
         summaryClassification[classificationIndex]["icls:amount"] = (summaryClassification[classificationIndex]["icls:amount"]/1 + line.netValue/1 ).toFixed(2);
      }

      invoiceDetails.push(line);
   }

}
```

- We have 3 line objects to th "lines" array.
- I iterate over the array to fill the info for every line.
- Each line has it's own incomeClassifications
- There's a summary object tha needs to collect each classification combination. (in the example I am using only 1 combination)
- After the iteration I am filling the summary fields that needs to be filled (totalNetValue,totalVatAmount,totalGrossValue).
- Then I using a findIndex() to find if the classification combination (type & category) exist inside summary.
- If findIndex is <0 (there isn't a combination that maches the line) I am adding the combination drom the line.
- Else, I am just Updating the amount of the given index with the addition of the current line.

**My Problem**

The else statement somehow changes the value os the incomeClassification of the 1st line. +

Given that from the first iteration, that key should be "10.00" following the code `line.incomeClassification["icls:amount"] = product.price.toFixed(2);` with the product.price beeing = 10.

Also, clearly the else statement code updates the summary properties and not the line ones `summaryClassification[classificationIndex]["icls:amount"] = (summaryClassification[classificationIndex]["icls:amount"]/1 + line.netValue/1 ).toFixed(2);`.

If I comment out the else statment at the and of makeLines():

- the 1st line classification amount is giving me the expected price of '10.00' but
- the summary classification amount is getting stucked at 10.00 because it doesn't
  get updated with each new line.

Maybe there is another way of doing this, but why is this happening in the first place?

Any help would be ENORMOUSLY appreciated...

Comment: I also tryied converting my object to string and re-parse it, like proposed in this question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51022523/changing-the-value-of-json-objects-key-changes-other-values-also) but it din't fixed it.

Comment: Can you post an MRE?  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.  My guess is the answer is simple, but too hard to see when looking 6 or 7 keys deep into the data.  Once you get it working, I worry this code will be too hard to maintain. Consider redesign, leaning on OO.

Comment: @danh You are right about visibillity. I am not sure I can do something about that, I thought to mask the first 3 layers with a single key. Nevertheless I 'll emulate the API using local data in an array, and construct a MRE.

Comment: Well I just edited the question and made the code to MRE. I also simplyfied the path to data, so now the calculation is more visible. @danh I just can't see it though, even now.  Also is the title good? Can I rename the question to somehting more relevant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Addressing the immediate problem: each `line` has a `lineClassification` prop, which is itself an object. As `lines` are being iterated, some of those lineClassification's are being placed in another array (`summaryClassification`). Subsequent turns of the outer loop are looking up elements of the array and mutating them, but these lineClassifications are the *same objects pointed to by the lines*.

Here's a much more minimal MRE to illustrate...

```js
const lines = [
  { name: 'line0', classificationObject: { name: 'class0', number: 10 } },
  { name: 'line1', classificationObject: { name: 'class1', number: 10 } },
  { name: 'line2', classificationObject: { name: 'class0', number: 10 } },
]

let summary = []

for (line of lines) {
  let classificationObject = line.classificationObject;
  let classificationName = classificationObject.name
  let index = summary.findIndex(s => s.name === classificationName);
  if (index == -1) {
    summary.push(classificationObject); // the problem is here.
    // the SAME classification object now appears in TWO places:
    // in the line object, and in the summary array
    // future mutations will be seen by both
  } else {
    // as a result, this line seems to modify two objects
    // it's really modifying one object, pointed to from multiple places
    summary[index].number += 12
  }
}

console.log("logging the summary, it's what we expect. The saved class0 classification has been mutated:")
console.log(summary)

console.log("But logging the lines, we're surprised to find line 0's classification object has been mutated. it happens because that same object was also placed in the summary array, and was mutated in a subequent turn of the loop:")
console.log(lines)
```

Fixing the MRE:

It's apparent that the `summaryClassification` array must be given *a copy* of the `lineClassification` object, one that can be mutated independently of the `line` it once belonged to.

```js
const lines = [
  { name: 'line0', classificationObject: { name: 'class0', number: 10 } },
  { name: 'line1', classificationObject: { name: 'class1', number: 10 } },
  { name: 'line2', classificationObject: { name: 'class0', number: 10 } },
]

let summary = []

for (line of lines) {
  // do some stuff that doesn't matter
  let classificationObject = line.classificationObject;
  let classificationName = classificationObject.name
  let index = summary.findIndex(s => s.name === classificationName);
  if (index == -1) {
    let classificationCopy = Object.assign({}, classificationObject);  // see here: make a copy
    summary.push(classificationCopy); // subsequent turns will
    // mutate the copy, leaving the original line alone
  } else {
    summary[index].number += 12
  }
}

console.log(summary)
console.log("logging the lines, see what we expect in line 0, an unchanged classification object")
console.log(lines)
```

In OP terms:

```
  if (classificationIndex < 0) { 
     let lineClassificationCopy = Object.assign({}, lineClassification);  // see here: make a copy
     summaryClassification.push(lineClassificationCopy);   
  } else {  // else if there is a an item in the array with the same categories, we add the amount of the item to the total
     summaryClassification[classificationIndex]["icls:amount"] = (summaryClassification[classificationIndex]["icls:amount"]/1 + line.netValue/1 ).toFixed(2);
  }
```

As an aside, the code represents numerical values as strings. A better practice is to represent numbers as numbers, do math on numbers, store intermediate results as numbers, etc, and convert the numbers to strings *only when* they must be presented to the user. For currency, this should be done using locale sensitive formatting.

A further aside is that the code appears to aim to do real-life-complexity business computing with insufficiently powerful technique. If this is a production system, I worry that the eventual owners will find it opaque and unmaintainable. I suggest reviewing and employing [object oriented concepts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object-oriented_JS) in the next revision.

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH for that! 1st of all you MRE code was briliant, well I guess I had to start somewhere to begin with. I got it now! I got it. I couldn't sleep well because I was thinking of this. The problem was at the if statement after all..., You saved my day, AND I learned something. Thank you again

Comment: @dahn as for the strings and numbers matter: I need to retain the double decimals at the end but .toFixed() method turns them to strings and I had headaches with that. Is there any other way I can retain double decimals without turning the numbers to strings? 

The result of that program must be turned to XML and posted to a goverment server, that returns errors if no double decimals are present. 

I have in mind to revision the code for final production. Now my main goal is just to have a paradime that works.

Comment: @AntonisVlachos - the key is to get numbers into a numerical representation as soon as possible (like from the api) and translate them to strings as late as possible (like in a UI or when serializing back to XML).  Numerical values as strings wastes space and time, makes the code hard to read, and -- worst of all -- will introduce errors.  (Consider applying a fractional tax like 5.6%, intermediate values stored as fixed(2) strings will lose precision. So dollars will be lost at the thousand dollar scale, hundreds lost at the hundred thousand scale, etc.

Comment: I' ll do just what you said. Thank you again